# How to correctly display item with dynamic size in Spark List?

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex-spark

I have an issue displaying some dynamic data in a Spark List.

I need to display some text from a data provider in a list. The list should display all the text without any scroll-bars and text can be formatted as in HTML.

I don't have control on the size of the list itself.

That said, I need to display items with a dynamic size based on the data to display. As the width of rendered item should be the width of the list itself, what I want is that different items displays with a dynamic height.

So far, I tried to use a custom `ItemRenderer` using a `TextArea` component. And here is a sample application that summarizes the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="450" minHeight="400">

    <s:List top="20" right="20" bottom="20" left="20" borderVisible="true"
            itemRenderer="CustomItemRenderer" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="justify"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <fx:Object time="00:01:23" level="DEBUG" message="This is a short log message"/>
                <fx:Object time="00:02:34" level="DEBUG" message="This is a not so short log message"/>
                <fx:Object time="00:03:45" level="DEBUG" message="This is not a short log message that won't display correctly on one line"/>
                <fx:Object time="00:04:56" level="DEBUG" message="This is a long message that will require two lines to be displayed correctly"/>
                <fx:Object time="00:05:23" level="DEBUG" message="Short again"/>
                <fx:Object time="00:06:34" level="DEBUG" message="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."/>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>
</s:Application>
```

With the code of my custom item renderer `CustomItemRenderer.mxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                autoDrawBackground="true"
                dataChange="handleDataChange(event)">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="hovered" />
        <s:State name="selected" />
    </s:states>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flashx.textLayout.elements.ParagraphElement;
            import flashx.textLayout.elements.SpanElement;
            import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function handleDataChange(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var flow:TextFlow = new TextFlow();

                var timeSpan:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
                timeSpan.text = "[" + data.time + "] ";
                timeSpan.fontFamily = "_mono";

                var levelSpan:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
                levelSpan.text = data.level + ": ";
                levelSpan.fontWeight = "bold";

                var messageSpan:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
                messageSpan.text = data.message;

                var paragraph:ParagraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
                paragraph.addChild(timeSpan);
                paragraph.addChild(levelSpan);
                paragraph.addChild(messageSpan);

                flow.addChild(paragraph);

                mainText.textFlow = flow;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:BorderContainer id="container" width="100%"
                       borderVisible="false" borderWeight="0"
                       dropShadowVisible="false">
        <s:layout>
            <s:BasicLayout />
        </s:layout>

        <s:TextArea id="mainText" width="100%" heightInLines="{NaN}"
                    borderVisible="false" selectable="true" editable="false">
        </s:TextArea>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

I tried to set the `heightInLines` property of my TextArea component to `NaN` as explained [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/18/creating-a-vertically-auto-resizing-spark-textarea-control-in-flex-4/) to have the textarea to auto-resiwe itself.

I also tried to set the height of the container equal to the height of the textArea, but this height is 0 right after I set the `TextFlow`, and if I wait for a resize event, the list doesn't show correctly either.

I tried to set the `horizontalAlign` property of the layout to `justify` instead of `contentJustify` as I read it [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/10/27/setting-word-wrapping-on-a-spark-list-control-in-flex-4/).

Sometimes, nothing will be displayed in the list until I click on an item. This will then display this item only and I'll have to do the same for each item.

I really don't understand what is going on and start to get lost after trying a lot of different things.
Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width and height of ItemRenderer. Example for your code:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        autoDrawBackground="true"
        dataChange="handleDataChange(event)"

        width="100%" height="100%">
```

p.s.
Maybe for better list performance you could try moving TextFlow creation out of ItemRenderer. For example, create textFlows and put them in list's dataprovider, and then use textflow from ItemRenderer's data value:

```
mainText.textFlow = data.flow;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the list to be displayed correctly, I made the following changes to my code:

First, as list items have a dynamic size, we have to tell the compiler not to use a virtual layout on the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="450" minHeight="400">

    <s:List top="20" right="20" bottom="20" left="20" borderVisible="true"
            useVirtualLayout="false"
            itemRenderer="CustomItemRenderer" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
        ...
    </s:List>
</s:Application>
```

Then, as mentionned by Nemi, we need to set the width of our item renderer (note that the height does not have to be specified here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                autoDrawBackground="true"
                width="100%"
                dataChange="handleDataChange(event)">
    ...
</s:ItemRenderer>
```